# Why am i getting the floating point error?

Tags: c++

To find count of numbers between two given sets such that set A has factors of the number and the number is a factor of set B

```
int getTotalX(vector <int> a, vector <int> b) {
    int c=0;
    long int hcf=findGCD(b,b.size()); //find hcf of set a 
    long int lcm=findlcm(a,a.size()); //find lcm of set b
    if(lcm<=hcf)
    {
        for(int i=lcm;i<=hcf;i++)
        {
            if(hcf%i==0 && i%lcm==0)    //to check for a no between two sets
                c++;
        }
        return c;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: Please migrate the text of the image into text for the question.

Comment: Copy the error text from hackerrank page and paste in question description.

Answer (score 0):

`hcf%i` and `i%lcm` require the right hand side (i and lcm respectively) to be non-zero, else you'll get a floating point exception.  You may find [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) of use in future